# Как реализовать групповой голосовой чат в браузере?

Tags: javascript, php, websocket, webrtc

Хотелось бы понять принцип реализации группового голосового чата по типу дискорда или google hangouts. В моём представлении это должен быть формат клент-сервер-клиент, чтобы на клиенты была минимально возможная нагрузка. По WebRTC я нашёл много информации про то как передавать данные в формате клиент-клиент и вытекающие сетки клиентов, где все друг другу должны передавать потоки, но это, естественно не подходит, т.к. клиенту придётся работать с огромной кучей медиа.

Другой вариант, который я нашёл, это нарезка потока на куски с помощью MediaRecorder и отправка этих кусков на сервер по websocket, который в свою очередь может рассылать их всем желающим клиентам. Этот вариант я и попробовал сделать. Но, если Chrome делает всё как и ожидалось, т.е. отправляет, получает части потока и воспроизводит их, то Firefox имеет своё мнение по минимально возможной длительности этих кусков. Т.е. если указать

```
mediarecorder.start(100);
```

то Firefox будет вызывать mediarecorder.ondataavailable раз в 100мс, но только примерно раз в 1с туда придут данные длинной в 1с. Плюс ко всему в Firefox autoplay на audio элементе с привязанным буфером срабатывает с большой задержкой, что в совокупности даёт громадное отставание в звуке.

И вот после многих дней моих приключений у меня есть браузерный JS для реализации клиента, PHP с вебсокетами для сервера и вопрос, что с этим всем можно сделать для реализации основной функции передачи-получения звука с микрофона с минимально возможной задержкой на большинстве основных браузерах. PHP в связке потому что наиболее доступен для меня сейчас, а проект для теста, чтобы понять принцип. Главное алгоритм работы клиента.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем основной вариант реализации групповых webrtc чатов это webrtc сервер, который будет получать все потоки и раздавать их пользователям. Общаться с сервером из приложения можно по api. Вариантов как получить такой сервер несколько. Основные это платные или опенсорс. Почитать размышления на тему можно здесь https://habr.com/ru/post/512496/
Сервера разные, писать приложение придётся под конкретный выбранный по докам.